# (objective-C) Can i use the same variable name in 2 different functions, but in the same file?

Tags: objective-c

Maybe this is implicit, but I am having doubts about it.

I have a .m file that has 2 different functions (or methods, as they are also called); but both functions uses a variable that I declare locally inside each function.

For sake of clarity, I like to use the same name; and from what I understand; there should be no problem in having both functions having the same variable name, since they will point to 2 different pointer locations in memory, so it should not matter.

Am I missing something or it is safe to do what I am doing? Should I use a different name? Should I use a global and change it accordingly, locally?

```
-(int) doThis
{

    int pressure = 1;

    ...do the calculations and return the results...

}

-(int) doThat
{

    int pressure = 5;
    ...do the calculations and return the results....

}
```

Comment: FYI - a function and a method are not the same thing. A method is associated with a class. A function is not.

Comment: Without further optimizing, local variables are pushed to the stack when entering a method/function/scope. They are popped off the stack when leaving it. Their names are irrelevant outside their scope as they do not exist. Code optimizing does not change those semantics.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, certainly.

You could even use the same variable name within different scopes in the same method.

Sample:

```
-(int) doThat
{

    int pressure = 5;

    for (int i = 0, i < pressure, i++) {
        int pressure = 10; // This is another variable!!! 
        pressure = 15;
        //Whatever
    }

    return pressure; //This would return 5!
}
```

I did that some times unintentionally. The errors that may result of that can be a pain in the a.. because they can be hard to see.

Just to add some more confustion: 
All within the same class, you could have an instance variable `pressure` which would hide a global variable `pressure`, if any. A method named `pressure` may have a parameter `pressure` which hides the instance variable. Then you may declare several variables `pressure` within different scopes within that method. All of them would hide their individually named counterparts in of the enclosing scope. And if you really want it confusing, then add a property named pressure to it. And that all may even work fine until you start loosing control or re-visit the same code a couple of weeks later.

Edit: the method `pressure` would clearly conflict with the getter of the property `pressure`. Meaning, it would work but the compiler would take the method as the getter given that it returns an object of the appropritate type. Or so.

Comment: Obviously +1 for the good answer, and I think it's on by default but I'm not entirely sure: enable the 'Hidden Local Variables' compiler warning if you want the compiler to check for where there's a possibility you've become confused. This is also probably why Apple has switched from the least syntax `@synthesize` creating an instance variable that matches the property name to one that starts with an underscore.

Comment: Yes, when it comes to explaining the underscore then I say that it is just a convention that helps separating the property from the ivar by name.

Comment: Much appreciated, and thanks for the extended explanation! I am coming form C++, so I am used to get slapped when something is not done in the way of the compiler, but with objective-C it is always a challenge, so just because don't raise an error or a warning doesn't necessarily mean that it will be fine :) Thanks again!

Comment: Yes. When I say it works fine then I do not mean it is advisable. :) BTW, scoping of local variables is not that much different in C++. In the end both started off as preprocessors for ANSI C, if I am not much mistaken.

Comment: Did I mention that even the class name could be `pressure`, although `Pressure` is more conventional.